# Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1) with wcf

Tags: wpf, wcf, .net-3.5

I am getting this error from my wcf service

System.Exception: Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).
error CS2001: Source file 'C:\WINNT\TEMP\igqfpel9.0.cs' could not be found
error CS2008: No inputs specified

Currently the identity that the service runs as does not have access to C:\WINNT\TEMP, my question is how do I change the location .Net 3.5 SP1 sticks temporary classes.  I would like to have it put everything in E:\Temp.  Is this possible?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try setting the `TEMP` environment variable:

```
        System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP", @"E:\Temp");
```